# ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream returning Null

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cyberneko

I migrated project from Eclipse to Android Studio.
App compiles fine, but it has a crash related to nekohtml library.

Inside HTMLEntities class

```
//filename = "res/HTMLlat1.properties"
final InputStream stream = HTMLEntities.class.getResourceAsStream(filename);
```

stream is always null. I tried to move file to the same folder as class and gave full path like this

```
filename = "/org/cyberneko/html/res/HTMLlat1.properties"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `filename = "/org/cyberneko/html/res/HTMLlat1.properties"` instead of `filename = "/org.cyberneko.html/res/HTMLlat1.properties"` or use relative paths. This could be explained in this way: jar (jar is an example, maybe you're running your code from `*.class` in some directory) is just some kind of file system with it's root ("/") and all the files in the packages are in some subdirectories and you should specify the paths for them.

Comment: thanks :) I tried this as well, it is null anyway. Modified question to be more specific

Comment: @Minas, ok, so, I'm not right, please, give us then the content of the resulting jar (with `jar tf`)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/guAm6gme    hmm /org/cyberneko/html/res/ is missing from the jar, but it is there in source

Comment: You really should take a closer look at the project's properties.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm new to IntelliJ, so I'm not sure why it is ignoring properties file. Eclipse add this files to the jar without any problem

Comment: Same problem here.., my path properly worked at Eclipse but Android Studio. Don't know what to do...

Comment: @CristyYG Show your `build.gradle` (under project root) please.

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xavey.android"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.1'
}

Comment: @CristyYG, okay, the where's your resources located?

Comment: @CristyYG I just asked where they're located in your FS. Something like `$PROJECT_ROOT/src/main/resources/com/xavey/android/util/...`

Comment: /src/main/java/com/xavey/android/util/xavey_properties_.properties

Comment: @CristyYG then I'm sure, I know the problem. Only java files are processed under `src/main/java/...`. You should move all your resources to `src/main/resources` (keeping the structure)

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg , the same.

Comment: I changed the path to /src/main/res/xavey_properties_.properties. Still null.

Comment: @CristyYG You should use exactly `resources`, not `res`!

Comment: My project only contains res folder. But when I made new project "helloworld". It does. Should I create manually resource folder under my project?

Comment: @CristyYG, yes, you have to.